# Multi step form ReactJs with Context API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-context

I am making simple multi step form using only react and context. I tried to use react-form-hook, but as I am a new in react it is a bit difficult for to understand it.
It shows **"Error: Maximum update depth exceeded."** when I add the user after confirming. Thanks for helping in advance

App.js

```
function App() {
  return (
    <GlobalProvider>
      <div className="container">
        <UserForm />
      </div>
    </GlobalProvider>
  );
}
```

GlobalState.jsx

```
import React, { createContext, useReducer } from 'react';
import AppReducer from './AppReducer';

const initialState = {
  users: []
}

// Create context
export const GlobalContext = createContext(initialState);

// Provider component
export const GlobalProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(AppReducer, initialState);

  // Actions
  function addUser(user) {
    dispatch({
      type: 'ADD_USERS',
      payload: user
    });
  }

  return (<GlobalContext.Provider value={{
    users: state.users,
    addUser
  }}>
    {children}
  </GlobalContext.Provider>);
}
```

AppReducer.jsx

```
export default (state, action) => {
  switch(action.type) {
    case 'ADD_USERS':
      return {
        ...state,
        users: [action.payload, ...state.users]
      }
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

UserForm.jsx

```
const UserForm = () => {
  const [step, setStep] = useState(1);
  const [user, setUser] = useState({
    firstname: '',
    lastname: ''
  })
  const { firstname, lastname } = user;

  const {addUser} = useContext(GlobalContext)

  // Go Forward to next step
  const nextStep = () => {
    setStep(step + 1)
  };

  // Go back to prev step
  const prevStep = () => {
    setStep(step - 1)
  };

  const handleChange = input => e => {
    setUser({ ...user, [e.target.name]: e.target.value })
  }


  if (step === 3) {

    const newUser = {
      id: Math.floor(Math.random() * 100000000),
      firstname,
      lastname
    }

    addUser(newUser)

    setTimeout(() => {
      setStep(1)
      clearAll()
    }, 1000);

  }

  const clearAll = () => {
    setUser({
      firstname: '',
      lastname: ''
    })
  }

  switch (step) {
    case 1:
      return (<UserInfo
        prevStep={prevStep}
        user={user}
        handleChange={handleChange}
      />);
    case 2:
      return (<Confirm
        nextStep={nextStep}
        prevStep={prevStep}
        user={user}
      />);
    case 3:
      return <Succuess />;
    default:
      return null
  }
}

export default UserForm
```

Confirm.jsx

```
const Confirm = ({nextStep, prevStep, user}) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1> Confirm</h1>
      <div>
        <p>{user.firstname}</p>
        <p>{user.lastname}</p>
      </div>

      <button onClick={(e) => prevStep()}  type="button" className="btn btn-primary">Back</button>
      <button onClick={(e) => nextStep()} type="button" className="btn btn-success">Submit</button>

    </div>
  )
}

export default Confirm
```

Comment: Main errors show in that lines
`function addUser(user) {
    dispatch({
      type: 'ADD_USERS',
      payload: user
    });
  }`
and in Userform `addUser(newUser)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this code should be inside a function and handled on event:

```
const checkFinalStep = () = {
  if (step === 3) {

    const newUser = {
      id: Math.floor(Math.random() * 100000000),
      firstname,
      lastname
   }

   addUser(newUser)

   setTimeout(() => {
      setStep(1)
      clearAll()
   }, 1000);

  }
}
```

Because currently it is simply inside the component, it will run every time react needs to re-render the component. And because it contains `addUser` reducer, it triggers updating the context which in turn renders the children, re-rendering your component again, recursively.

Comment: And because it only activates when `step === 3`, you only see the problem after you confirm

Comment: Where and How can I call this function?

Comment: i am assuming when the next click happens.

Comment: Thanks it works as I want, the only thing i have to pass `step` prosperity to   `checkFinalStep` function

Comment: You may want to think about using useEffect. May be clearer and easier if you needed to things like this on every step

Comment: Now, I am facing with update function. Could you check it please?
https://codesandbox.io/s/musing-lichterman-1iyrs

Comment: Because it is a map function, you have to return something (in this case `user`). if your actions and payloads are wired correctly just add this line: `return check ? action.payload.user : user`

Comment: i cant get to your update form so, i don't know what you are passing with the action. if you call `updateUser(user)` then you do `action.payload.id === id` and `return check ? action.payload : user`

Comment: Looks like what you are passing is the list of users in the action call. Instead you want to pass the right user only,  for simplicity reasons.

Comment: Sorry, it was spelling error, after changing some lines. Now It works perfectly. Much appreciate